# How to do MD5 hashing in ASP.NET web pages (razor syntax/cshtml)

Tags: razor, asp.net-webpages

I am converting a PHP page into ASP.NET web pages with RAZOR syntax(cshtml).
I know how to use MD5 in c# but cannot get any help to do in RAZOR syntax.
can someone help me to convert following PHP line into Razor syntax.

```
if(isset($_POST['login-check']) && $_POST['login-check'] == 'request'){

$CampusName = $_POST['campusid'];
$studentID = $_POST['studentid'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$salt = "portal";
$pass = md5($pass.''.$salt);
```

}

this line of code

```
$pass = md5($pass.''.$salt);
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor syntax is C#. But you shouldn't be using MD5 to hash passwords. It's a [broken algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5). The Web Pages framework includes a `Crypto` helper class with a `HashPassword` method that uses a proper algorithm: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/200/the-simplemembershipprovider-secure-passwords-and-the-crypto-helper. If you don't want to use the SimpleMembershipProvider for managing user accounts, you can use the helper methods on their own:

```
if(IsPost()){
    var CampusName = Request["campusid"];
    var studentID = Request["studentid"];
    var pass = Crypto.HashPassword(Request["password"]);
    // no need for messing about with salts, already taken care of
}
```

Then you use the `VerifyHashedPassword` method to compare a submitted password with the hashed value that you stored.

Comment: Thanks Mike Brind, I got it.